# SQL Server Pagination with different line number per page

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pagination

I have a table in SQL Server database containing :

- `int` value (column's name : `Value`)
- `datetime` value (column's name : `Date`)
- `bit` value (column's name : `LastLineOfPage`)

I would like to make a pagination query over this table. The logic of the pagination is the following :

- The query must return lines corresponding to a given page (parameter `@PageNumber`), after sorting lines by the `Date` column
- Also, the query must give the `SUM` of all the previous pages lines
- The line number per page is not fixed : by default it's 14 lines per page, but if the bit `LastLineOfPage` is true, then the page contain only lines until the one with the true value

Here is a synthetic view of the process :

[image]

Here is the data in text :

```
ID  DATE      VALUE LASTLINEOFPAGE
1   07/10/2006  10  0
2   14/10/2006  12  0
3   21/10/2006  4   1
4   28/10/2006  6   0
5   04/11/2006  8   1
6   25/11/2006  125 0
7   02/12/2006  1   0
8   09/12/2006  5   0
9   16/12/2006  45  0
10  30/12/2006  1   1
```

So, the query receiving `@PageNumber`, and also `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage` (which will be equal to 14 but maybe one day that will change).

Could you help me in the design of this query or SQL function ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post your data as text? we cant copy / paste from pictures. Is this mySql or Sql-Server and what version? And what you need a query receiving a @page parameter?

Comment: A single query will not do this. You'll need a separate query for (at least) the previous page SUM. Also, a better schema would be to just store a page number or page ID instead of a last-line indicator.

Comment: Sql server version? so if you have  `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage = 10` and there is 15 rows before the next `LASTLINEOFPAGE = 1` you only show 10 rows and next page 5?

Comment: Yes exactely : 10 lines, then the 5 on the next page. SQL Server version 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

I added few rows to illustrate how it works when there are more rows per page than `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage`. In this example I'll use `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage=5` and you'll see how extra pages were generated.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, dt date, VALUE int, LASTLINEOFPAGE bit);
INSERT INTO @T(ID, dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE) VALUES
(1 , '2006-10-07', 10 , 0),
(2 , '2006-10-14', 12 , 0),
(3 , '2006-10-21', 4  , 1),
(4 , '2006-10-28', 6  , 0),
(5 , '2006-11-04', 8  , 1),
(6 , '2006-11-25', 125, 0),
(7 , '2006-12-02', 1  , 0),
(8 , '2006-12-09', 5  , 0),
(9 , '2006-12-16', 45 , 0),
(10, '2006-12-30', 1  , 1),

(16, '2007-01-25', 125, 0),
(17, '2007-02-02', 1  , 0),
(18, '2007-02-09', 5  , 0),
(19, '2007-02-16', 45 , 0),
(20, '2007-02-20', 1  , 0),
(26, '2007-02-25', 125, 0),
(27, '2007-03-02', 1  , 0),
(28, '2007-03-09', 5  , 0),
(29, '2007-03-10', 5  , 0),
(30, '2007-03-11', 5  , 0),
(31, '2007-03-12', 5  , 0),
(32, '2007-03-13', 5  , 1),

(41, '2007-10-07', 10 , 0),
(42, '2007-10-14', 12 , 0),
(43, '2007-10-21', 4  , 1);
```

**Query**

Run it step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE and examine intermediate results to understand what it does.

`CTE_FirstLines` sets the `FirstLineOfPage` flag to 1 for the first line of the page instead of the last.

`CTE_SimplePages` uses a cumulative `SUM` to calculate the simple page numbers based on `FirstLineOfPage` page breaks.

`CTE_ExtraPages` uses `ROW_NUMBER` divided by `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage` to calculate extra page numbers if there is a page that has more than `@DefaultLineNumberPerPage` rows.

`CTE_CompositePages` combines simple page numbers with extra page numbers to make a single composite page "Number". It assumes that there will be less than 1000 rows between original `LASTLINEOFPAGE` flags. If it is possible to have such long sequence of rows, increase the `1000` constant and consider using `bigint` type for `CompositePageNumber` column.

`CTE_FinalPages` uses `DENSE_RANK` to assign sequential numbers without gaps for each final page.

```
DECLARE @DefaultLineNumberPerPage int = 5;
DECLARE @PageNumber int = 3;

WITH
CTE_FirstLines
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE
        ,CAST(ISNULL(LAG(LASTLINEOFPAGE) 
            OVER (ORDER BY dt), 1) AS int) AS FirstLineOfPage
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_SimplePages
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage
        ,SUM(FirstLineOfPage) OVER(ORDER BY dt 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SimplePageNumber
    FROM CTE_FirstLines
)
,CTE_ExtraPages
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage, SimplePageNumber
        ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SimplePageNumber ORDER BY dt) - 1)
            / @DefaultLineNumberPerPage AS ExtraPageNumber
    FROM CTE_SimplePages
)
,CTE_CompositePages
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage, SimplePageNumber, ExtraPageNumber
        ,SimplePageNumber * 1000 + ExtraPageNumber AS CompositePageNumber
    FROM CTE_ExtraPages
)
,CTE_FinalPages
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage, SimplePageNumber, ExtraPageNumber
        ,CompositePageNumber
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CompositePageNumber) AS FinalPageNumber
    FROM CTE_CompositePages
)
,CTE_Sum
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage, SimplePageNumber, ExtraPageNumber
        ,CompositePageNumber
        ,FinalPageNumber
        ,SUM(Value) OVER(ORDER BY FinalPageNumber, dt
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SumCumulative
    FROM CTE_FinalPages
)
SELECT
    ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, FirstLineOfPage, SimplePageNumber, ExtraPageNumber
    ,CompositePageNumber
    ,FinalPageNumber
    ,SumCumulative
FROM CTE_Sum
--  WHERE FinalPageNumber = @PageNumber
ORDER BY dt
;
```

**Result with the final `WHERE` filter commented out**

Here is the full result with all intermediate columns to illustrate how the query works.

```
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
| ID |     dt     | VALUE | Lst | Fst | Simple | Extra | Composite | Final | TotalValue |
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
|  1 | 2006-10-07 |    10 |   0 |   1 |      1 |     0 |      1000 |     1 |         10 |
|  2 | 2006-10-14 |    12 |   0 |   0 |      1 |     0 |      1000 |     1 |         22 |
|  3 | 2006-10-21 |     4 |   1 |   0 |      1 |     0 |      1000 |     1 |         26 |
|  4 | 2006-10-28 |     6 |   0 |   1 |      2 |     0 |      2000 |     2 |         32 |
|  5 | 2006-11-04 |     8 |   1 |   0 |      2 |     0 |      2000 |     2 |         40 |
|  6 | 2006-11-25 |   125 |   0 |   1 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        165 |
|  7 | 2006-12-02 |     1 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        166 |
|  8 | 2006-12-09 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        171 |
|  9 | 2006-12-16 |    45 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        216 |
| 10 | 2006-12-30 |     1 |   1 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        217 |
| 16 | 2007-01-25 |   125 |   0 |   1 |      4 |     0 |      4000 |     4 |        342 |
| 17 | 2007-02-02 |     1 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     0 |      4000 |     4 |        343 |
| 18 | 2007-02-09 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     0 |      4000 |     4 |        348 |
| 19 | 2007-02-16 |    45 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     0 |      4000 |     4 |        393 |
| 20 | 2007-02-20 |     1 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     0 |      4000 |     4 |        394 |
| 26 | 2007-02-25 |   125 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     1 |      4001 |     5 |        519 |
| 27 | 2007-03-02 |     1 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     1 |      4001 |     5 |        520 |
| 28 | 2007-03-09 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     1 |      4001 |     5 |        525 |
| 29 | 2007-03-10 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     1 |      4001 |     5 |        530 |
| 30 | 2007-03-11 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     1 |      4001 |     5 |        535 |
| 31 | 2007-03-12 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      4 |     2 |      4002 |     6 |        540 |
| 32 | 2007-03-13 |     5 |   1 |   0 |      4 |     2 |      4002 |     6 |        545 |
| 41 | 2007-10-07 |    10 |   0 |   1 |      5 |     0 |      5000 |     7 |        555 |
| 42 | 2007-10-14 |    12 |   0 |   0 |      5 |     0 |      5000 |     7 |        567 |
| 43 | 2007-10-21 |     4 |   1 |   0 |      5 |     0 |      5000 |     7 |        571 |
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

To get only one given page uncomment the `WHERE` filter in the final `SELECT`.

**Result with the final `WHERE` filter**

```
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
| ID |     dt     | VALUE | Lst | Fst | Simple | Extra | Composite | Final | TotalValue |
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
|  6 | 2006-11-25 |   125 |   0 |   1 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        165 |
|  7 | 2006-12-02 |     1 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        166 |
|  8 | 2006-12-09 |     5 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        171 |
|  9 | 2006-12-16 |    45 |   0 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        216 |
| 10 | 2006-12-30 |     1 |   1 |   0 |      3 |     0 |      3000 |     3 |        217 |
+----+------------+-------+-----+-----+--------+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

The `TotalValue` in the last row gives you the total page value that you want to show at the bottom of the page. If you sum all values on *this* page (125+1+5+45+1 = 177) and subtract it from the last `TotalValue` (217-177 = 40) you'll get the total of previous pages that you want to show at the top of the page. You'd better do these calculations on the client.

Comment: That looks great ! Thanks ! I will try it on my real database with thousands of lines, to check the time response.

Comment: @user1592596, it would be interesting to see how it works on real data. An index on `(date) include (VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE)` should help.

Comment: How do you implement this index ? Is is necessary to implement index on ID field or is it the case by default ? (i'm not an expert in SQL Server)

Comment: @user1592596, index is created by `CREATE INDEX` statement. Like this: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Date] ON [dbo].[TableName]
(
 [Date] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([VALUE], [LASTLINEOFPAGE])
`. On the other hand, few thousand rows is too small. You may not need any index at all.

Comment: That seems to work very well with 4000 lines ! Thanks a lot. One last question : I would like to add in as separate column the MAX(FinalPageNumber) of all the lines (new column called "MaxPageNumber"). Of course the value inside will be the same for each lines, but I need to read the value in my C# code later. On the last query , I tried SELECT
    ID,dt, VALUE, LASTLINEOFPAGE, MAX(FinalPageNumber) but that seems to be more complicated

Comment: @user1592596, you are welcome. I'd run two separate queries. First query would return the total number of pages: `SELECT MAX(FinalPageNumber) ...`. It would return one row, with one number. Second query would have the filter `WHERE FinalPageNumber = @PageNumber` and would return only the rows of the given page.

Comment: Yes that's a way to do that, but if I imagine to run the query with thousands of lines, maybe it will take 2 or 3 seconds. If I run the query two times, that means 6 seconds... that's why it would be maybe good to pass the MAX(PageNumber) in a distinct column, to get the value even if the query is called one time ?

Comment: @user1592596, did you measure the run time of both queries? Was it 3 + 3 seconds? A query on a table with 4K rows should run for a fraction of a second. In any case, this is how I'd do it. I don't think that a single complex query that returns a total number as an extra column would be faster than two separate queries. If you really need such single query, try to write it yourself and ask a new question if you come across problems that you can't solve.

Comment: ok thanks, i will do that! I didn't measured the run time yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution. Still doesnt count default page size, but can give you an idea. So let me know what you think. Hope you are familiar with CTE's. Test each step so you see what are the partial results.

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/QMEAES3416)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT [ID], [DATE], [VALUE], [LASTLINEOFPAGE],
           SUM([VALUE]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) as Total,
           SUM([LASTLINEOFPAGE]) OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) as page_group
    FROM Table1
),
pages as (
    SELECT c1.[ID], c1.[Total],
           CASE WHEN c1.[ID] = 1         THEN 0
                WHEN c1.[ID] = m.[minID] THEN c1.[page_group] -1
                                         ELSE c1.[page_group]
           END as [page_group]
    FROM cte as c1
    JOIN (SELECT [page_group], MIN([ID]) as minID
          FROM cte
          GROUP BY [page_group]) m
      ON c1.[page_group] = m.[page_group]
)
SELECT c.[ID], c.[DATE], c.[VALUE], c.[LASTLINEOFPAGE],
       (SELECT MAX([Total])
        FROM pages p2
        WHERE p2.[page_group] = p.[page_group]) as [Total],
       p.[page_group]

FROM cte c
JOIN pages p
  ON c.[ID] = p.[id]
```

As you can see the total and the page are in the aditional column and you shouldnt display those on your app

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot juan Carlos !